# How to parse body class with Xpath?

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to parse a page with Xpath, but I don't manage to get the body class.

Here is what I'm trying :

```
<?php

$url = 'http://figurinepop.com/mickey-paintbrush-disney-funko';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href'); 
foreach($nodes as $node) { 
    $canonical = $node->nodeValue; 
}
$nodes = $xpath->query('//html/body/@class'); 
foreach($nodes as $node) { 
   $bodyclass = $node->nodeValue; 
}

$output['canonical'] = $canonical;
$output['bodyclass'] = $bodyclass;

echo '<pre>'; print_r ($output); echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Here is what I get :

```
Array
(
     [canonical] => http://figurinepop.com/mickey-paintbrush-disney-funko
     [bodyclass] => 
)
```

It's working with many elements (title, canonical, div...) but the body class.
I've tested the Xpath query with a chrome extension and it seems well written.

What is wrong ?

Comment: hmm, seems to work just fine on my end, i just hid the errors with `libxml_use_internal_errors`

Comment: @Ghost : you mean that you get the bodyclass value (which is "dc-post") ? I don't understand why it remains empty on my end...

Comment: here's a fiddle https://www.tehplayground.com/yckWaXb0mq3SikTM

Comment: OK, thanks... Works for me in the fiddle, but still empty on my end with the exactly same code... I don't understand... I tried with several server, brower...

Comment: hmm, odd, probably not code related, even works on PHP 5.6. try to update php extension if possible, or try other in machine, so that you can compare environments used

Comment: *btw* You can fetch values directly: `$canonical = $xpath->evaluate('string(//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href)');
$bodyclass = $xpath->evaluate('string(//html/body/@class)');` No need for the loops.